# ASP.NET MVC input field with datetime datatype is not refreshing its value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am building some form (ASP.NET MVC). I have there a datetime input field. I am passing viewmodel to the view with initialized value of property with date (DateTimeOffset.Now). The problem is that date-time picker that is generated in a browser have also seconds and miliseconds that I don't need.

I saw asnwers for similiar questions, and people were advising to add format, but when I add format, then input field is not generated with default value (the one passed with viewmodel), visible value is: "dd.mm.rrrr --:--" (probably default date formatting for my country). When I look into html, I see that in value property there is proper value ("17.01.2022 12:22").

When I select value from default datetime picker, than everything is ok, even when I submit form (httpost) and values are reloaded.

```
<form class="form" asp-action="ScheduleItemsAdd" method="post">
<div class="form-group d-flex flex-column" >
    <label asp-for="FirstVisitDateTime" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="FirstVisitDateTime" class="form-control" asp-format="{0:dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm}">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Add</button>
</div>
```

When I remove "asp-format="{0:dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm}" it will load initial value, but will show seconds and milisecond in date time picker.

```
    private DateTimeOffset? _firstVisitDateTime;
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(  ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

    public DateTimeOffset FirstVisitDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            if (_firstVisitDateTime.HasValue)
            {
                return _firstVisitDateTime.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return DateTimeOffset.Now;
            }
        }
        set { _firstVisitDateTime = value; }
    }
```

I want to load initial value (or just DateTime.Now) and use default date-time picker without seconds and milisseconds.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch:

```
[DataType(DataType.Datetime)]
```

to:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

This will only display the date portion in the browser.

Comment: I split it into two fields, one with date, second with time and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it is okay , you can change your input field display type as string instead and then at backed you can use C# code to format date time i.e.

```
mydatetime.ToString("{0:dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm}");
```

and at frontend you can use moment.JS to change the input field's format